# How to interpret the report of perf

Tags: c++, c++11, profiler, perf

I'm learning how to use the tool `perf` to profile my c++ project. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>


std::mutex mtx;
long long_val = 0;

void do_something(long &val)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    for(int j=0; j<1000; ++j)
        val++;
}


void thread_func()
{
    for(int i=0; i<1000000L; ++i)
    {
        do_something(long_val);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> threads;
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread(thread_func))));
    }
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        threads[i]->join();
    }
    threads.clear();
    std::cout << long_val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it, I run `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lpthread -g` and then I get the executable file named `a.out`.

Then I run `perf record --call-graph dwarf -- ./a.out` and wait for 10 seconds, then I press `Ctrl+c` to interrupt the `./a.out` because it needs too much time to execute.

Lastly, I run `perf report -g graph --no-children` and here is the output:

[image]

My goal is to find which part of the code is the heaviest. So it seems that this output could tell me `do_something` is the heaviest part(46.25%). But when I enter into `do_something`, I can not understand what it is: `std::_Bind_simple`, `std::thread::_Impl` etc.

So how to get more useful information from the output of `perf report`? Or we can't get more except the fact that `do_something` is the heaviest?

Comment: All symbols beginning with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like e.g. `_Bind_simple`) is reserved in all scopes for the "implementation" (compiler and standard library). See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for details. What that means in your case is that those symbols are internal and private for the "implementation", and are probably internal helper functions or classes of the standard library.

Comment: You forgot to enable optimization at all when you compiled, so all the little functions that should normally inline away are actually getting called.  Add `-O3` or at least `-O2` to your g++ command line.  Optionally also profile-guided optimization if you really want gcc to do a good job on hot loops.

Comment: Yes, the information you get when you expand `do_something` is the call stack. So what you can see here is that `do_something` was called by `thread_func` which was in turn called by `std::_Bind_simple<...>::_M_invoke<>` and so on.

Comment: Not directly related, but why use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> threads;` instead of simple `std::vector<std::thread> threads;`? If issue is calling constructor, you can do it with `thread.emplace_back(thread_func);`

Comment: @PeterCordes  oh thanks a lot. It helps. I just tried `-O3` and now `perf report` shows me the hotspot is `futex_wake` and `futex_wait_setup`. This is useful.

Comment: @Frodyne  Ok, got it. So what I need is not the call stack of `do_something`... Anyway, in this case, `-O3` helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Peter Cordes, I pose this answer. If you have something more useful, please feel free to pose your answers.

> You forgot to enable optimization at all when you compiled, so all the
>   little functions that should normally inline away are actually getting
>   called. Add -O3 or at least -O2 to your g++ command line. Optionally
>   also profile-guided optimization if you really want gcc to do a good
>   job on hot loops.

After adding `-O3`, the output of `perf report` becomes:

[image]

Now we can get something useful from `futex_wake` and `futex_wait_setup` as we should know that `mutex` in C++11 is implemented by `futex` of Linux. So the result is that `mutex` is the hotspot in this code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your mutexes are waiting on each other forcing your program to hit the scheduler often.

You would get better performance if you used fewer threads.

Comment: Yeah you are totally right. I think people can figure it out easily by reading the source code. The problem is to make `perf` to tell us this fact.